# Cannot assign requested address with YugabyteDB and Docker Volume

Tags: database, docker, yugabytedb

Problem when using yugabyte with persistence volume in docker.
On first run everything work fine, but when re-create container with existing volume, it fail to start:

```
master.err :
./../src/yb/master/master_main.cc:131] Network error (yb/util/net/socket.cc:325): Error binding socket to 172.28.0.3:7100: Cannot assign requested address (system error 99)
    @          0x2938618  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @          0x29394d3  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @          0x29399cf  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @          0x2677cde  main
    @     0x7fb112f46825  __libc_start_main
    @          0x260802e  _start (edited)
```

There is a yugabyted.conf in yb-data/conf  with the ip is written there
When we re-create container the container will get new ip but the ip in yugabyted.conf is old ip address of container

```
...
"advertise_address": "172.28.0.3", 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

When starting with `yugabyted`, the directory set by `--base_dir` holds the configuration in `conf/yugabyted.conf`, and the data directory in `data` which is set by `--fs_data_dirs` when starting `yb-master` and `yb-tserver`.

If you want the data directory in the volume but not the configuration, you can set it with:

```
--tserver_flags=fs_data_dirs=/ybdata --master_flags=fs_data_dirs=/ybdata
```

and leave --base_dir within the container

Another possibility if you want the configuration in the external volume is to use a configuration that is not dependent on container addresses, like with:

```
--advertise_address=0.0.0.0
```

which will listen on all interfaces